# Vector as a Private member of a Class defined with pointer: no error but strange behavior

Tags: c++, vector, private

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work: no error, it just send me the following results:

Hello world!
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.656 s
Press any key to continue.

I defined listInt as a vector in private member. Is it coming from the pointer that I use to define the Class1 object?

```
    #include "Class1.h"
    using namespace std;

    Class1::Class1()
    {
        int age(10);
        listInt[0]=age;
        cout <<"address Vector1: "<<&listInt[0] << " -  value1:"<<listInt[0] <<  endl;

    }
    Class1::~Class1()
    {
        //delete listInt;
    }
    void Class1::ClassPrintOut() const
    {

    cout << listInt[0] <<  endl;

    }
```

Class1.cpp

```
    #ifndef CLASS1_H_INCLUDED
    #define CLASS1_H_INCLUDED
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>

    class Class1
    {
        public:
    Class1();
    ~Class1();
    void ClassPrintOut() const;


        private:
    std::vector<int> listInt;


    };
    #endif
```

Main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Class1.h"
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        Class1 *test(0);
    test =new Class1();
    test->ClassPrintOut();

    delete test;
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `Class1 test(0); test = new Class1();` should just be `Class1 test = new Class1();`.

Comment: `listInt` does not have an object at index 0, so assigning `age` to `listInt[0]` won't do anything good and printing its value won't do anything meaningful. The code should either set the size of `listInt` in the constructor so that there are elements it can access or use `listInt.push_back(age)` to create an element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not explicitly initialize your `std::vector<int> listInt` member. This means the default constructor of `std::vector<int>` will be used. **It initializes a vector with initial size of 0**, thus accessing it with index `0` is invalid.

To give a initial size to your list, you should do:

```cpp
Class1::Class1() : listInt(/* the initial size */) { ... }
```

This gives you a vector with size of `/* the initial size */` and all elements initialized to zero.

If you want to change the size by dynamically adding elements, use `push_back` or `emplace_back`:

```cpp
listInt.push_back(/* element to add */);
listInt.emplace_back(/* element to add */);
```

Both append an element to the end of the vector and increase the vector's size by one.

The difference is that `emplace_back` constructs the new element in-place using the parameters you passed to it, but `push_back` always copies (or move) the element. In your case (`std::vector<int>`), they make no difference.